# sql pivot for dynamically generated columns

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am unable to figure out how to set rows to cols or use pivot for dynamically generated cols.
There are 3 tables - tblEmp, tblLeaveType & tblEmpLeaves. The result set now is

```
EmpId Name Type Days
--------------------
 1    john  al   5
 1    john  cl   2
 2    smith al   3
 3    jack  sl   4
```

I would like to get it the foll way.

```
EmpId Name    al     cl     sl
--------------------------------
 1    john    5      2     null
 2    smith   3     null   null
 3    jack    null  null   4
```

The leave types can add dynamically. Please check the fiddle here -
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ad02e/1
Using sql server 2008, c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the final result using SQL only, then you can implement the PIVOT function.  Before trying to write a dynamic SQL version you should always write a hard-coded version first so you can get the basic logic correct.

If you had a limited number of `types` that you needed to convert into columns, then you could use:

```
select id, name, al, cl, sl
from
(
  select e.id, e.name, lt.type, l.days 
  from tblEmp e
  left outer join tblEmpLeaves l 
    on e.id = l.empId
  left outer join tblLeaveType lt 
    on l.leaveId = lt.Id
) d
pivot
(
  max(days)
  for type in (al, cl, sl)
) piv
order by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ad02e/6).

But if you are going to have an unknown number of values, then you have to use dynamic SQL and you would place the code in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(type) 
                    from tblLeaveType
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, name,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select e.id, e.name, lt.type, l.days 
              from tblEmp e
              left outer join tblEmpLeaves l 
                on e.id = l.empId
              left outer join tblLeaveType lt 
                on l.leaveId = lt.Id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(days)
                for type in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by id'

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ad02e/7). They both give you the result:

```
| ID |  NAME |     AL |     CL |     SL |
|----|-------|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |  john |      5 |      2 | (null) |
|  2 | smith |      3 | (null) | (null) |
|  3 |  jack | (null) | (null) |      4 |
```